# migrating Snowflake to Okta for some users and not for others

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on

I'm working on migrating Snowflake under Okta however there will be some users that will not have access to Okta, i.e, contract employees. I know for the migration I'll have to run a security integration, but does this mean that those users won't be able to access Snowflake since it will be behind Okta? And is there a way to allow a few to access even once we move Snowflake to Okta?

```
use role accountadmin;
CREATE SECURITY INTEGRATION OKTAINTEGRATION
    TYPE = SAML2
    ENABLED = TRUE 
    SAML2_ISSUER = 'http://www.okta.com/<YOUR ENTITY ID>'
    SAML2_SSO_URL = '<YOUR IDP SSO URL>'
    SAML2_PROVIDER = OKTA
    SAML2_X509_CERT = '<YOUR AUTHENTICATION CERTIFICATE in ONE LINE>'
    SAML2_SP_INITIATED_LOGIN_PAGE_LABEL = 'MYSSO'
    SAML2_ENABLE_SP_INITIATED = TRUE;
```

Docs I'm using: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Setup-SSO-Using-Okta-with-Snowflake-new-URL-format

Comment: You can have users in Snowflake who can authenticate using a password or key pair without Okta

Comment: @aek - just want to confirm though, once I run the security integration query above will that require all users that have snowflake to login via Okta or can those that don't have Okta continue using a pw with two-factor authentication? I couldn't find anything regarding this in the docs

Comment: When you create Okta integration on your Snowflake account login page you get the button Sign In using Okta, while username and password fields will remain available for those usernames who e.g. do not have your Okta account. MFA is a [user based configuration](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa) so "not-Okta" users can still enable that to use with the basic password authentication.

Comment: I summed up my comments as an answer. I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake support integration with SAML 2.0 compliant IdP such as Okta or Azure AD. When security integration created the corp users can sign in their Snowflake account through their IdP accounts, or by clicking the button: "Sign In using Okta" (or other IdP) which will appear when they access Snowflake account via account URL.

At the same time the "Username" and "Password" fields will remain available. The users who do not have IdP accounts can use their credentials to sign in Snowflake.

Also they will be able to enroll [MFA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa) or use [Key-Pair](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth), e.g. for any external clients/driver to access Snowflake independently from the IdP.

Comment: once we have the users in Okta how do we disable them from logging in via snowflake w. their username and pw? It seems we can still login with our username / pw and via Okta, but we only want them to be able to login w. Okta (the ones that have it)